# ElasticSearch - fuzzy search java api results are not proper

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have indexed sample documents in elasticsearch and trying to search using fuzzy query. But am not getting any results when am search by using Java fuzzy query api.

Please find my below mapping script :

```
PUT productcatalog
 {
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "attr_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "letter",
                    "char_filter": [
                        "html_strip"
                    ],
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding", "stemmer_minimal_english"]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "stemmer_minimal_english" : {
                    "type" : "stemmer",
                    "name" : "minimal_english"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "values": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "attr_analyzer"
                },
                "catalog_type": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "catalog_id":{
                    "type": "long"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please find my sample data.

```
PUT productcatalog/doc/1
{
    "catalog_id" : "343",
    "catalog_type" : "series",
    "values" : "Activa Rooftop, valves, VG3000, VG3000FS, butterfly, ball"
}


PUT productcatalog/doc/2
{
    "catalog_id" : "12717",
    "catalog_type" : "product",
    "values" : "Activa Rooftop, valves"
}
```

Please find my search script :

```
GET productcatalog/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "values" : {
                "query" : " activa rooftop VG3000",
                "operator" : "and",
                 "boost": 1.0,
                "fuzziness": 2,
                "prefix_length": 0,
                "max_expansions": 100


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am getting the below results for the above query :

```
{
  "took": 239,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.970927,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "productcatalog",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.970927,
        "_source": {
          "catalog_id": "343",
          "catalog_type": "series",
          "values": "Activa Rooftop, valves, VG3000, VG3000FS, butterfly, ball"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But if i use the below Java API for the same fuzzy search am not getting any results out of it.

Please find my below Java API query for fuzzy search :

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
               .must(QueryBuilders.fuzzyQuery("values", keyword).boost(1.0f).prefixLength(0).maxExpansions(100));
```

**Update 1**

I have tried with the below query

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.matchQuery(QueryBuilders.fuzzyQuery("values", keyword).boost(1.0f).prefixLength(0).maxExpansions(100));
```

But am not able to pass `QueryBuilders` inside `matchQuery`. Am getting this suggestion while am writing this query `The method matchQuery(String, Object) in the type QueryBuilders is not applicable for the arguments (FuzzyQueryBuilder)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mentioned java query is not a `match` query. It's a `must` query. you should use `matchQuery` instead of `boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.fuzzyQuery())`

**Update 1**:

[fuzzy query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) is a **term** query while  [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) is a **full text** query.

Also don't forget that in match query the default Operator is `or` operator which you should change it to `and` like your dsl query.

Comment: I have updated the same in my query., Please find my updated query in my question itself. Its not working.

Comment: you shouldn't pass a `fuzzyQuery` to a `matchQuery`, you can use `matchQuery(...).fuzziness(Fuzziness.TWO).prefixLength(0)` or sth  like this

Comment: also try to set `.operator(Operator.AND))`  to your `matchQuery`